# T-SQL - Expanding text in local parameter based on values from multiple tables, without using if statements

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

The problem is as follows: I have  some parameters

```
Declare @testParam nvarchar(max) = '',
Declare @ID int = 3
```

and I have many complex tables and all of them have a column that is named differently, but resembles some kind of status that is of type `BIT`.

| ID | Status | some other values... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | ... |
| 3 | 1 | ... |
| 4 | 1 | ... |

I want to expend text of `@testParam` every time the `Status` value = 1 for the record matching my `ID`. The text I need to add to this `@testParam` will be different for every table.

As for example:

```
select @testParam = @testParam + 'Full capacity ' 
from CapacityTable
where CapacityStatus= 1 and ID = @ID

select @testParam = @testParam + 'Not enough coal ' 
from CoalTable
where LackOfCoal = 1 and ID = @ID

select @testParam = @testParam + 'Too low temperature' 
from OvenTable 
where OvenStatus = 1 and ID = @ID

select @testParam as Result
```

If all of the select statments meet the conditions, the result that I expect would look like:

| Result |
| --- |
| Full capacity Not enough coal Too low temperature |

I know I could achieve this by using many `IF` statements, but I need this query to be as optimal as possible. Unless using `IF` statements doesn't change much in case of execution time I'm looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: Don't really understand what you are asking here, can you please add some example data and the output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @iamdave added what you've asked for :)

Comment: Seems to me you should be looking for a solution that works correctly FIRST before you try to "optimize it" to achieve some undefined objective. String aggregation is a common topic - TSQL has [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in current versions - alternatives exist and have been posted many times for older versions.

Comment: And perhaps adding a computed column or other conversion technique to associated a numeric value to a string description is a good idea as well. You don't want to keep writing these same descriptions in every query that needs to reference them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66317406/how-to-view-the-variable-value-in-sql-server/66317595#66317595 for why not to use the syntax you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one way acomplish it by using case clause, but again if there is a better way (in case of performance) I would like to know about it.

Solution using case clause:

```
select @testParam = @testParam + 
case 
   when CapacityStatus = 1
   then 'Full capacity ' 
   else ''
end
from CapacityTable
where ID = @ID
```

Apply code above for every table you need in analogical way.