# How to view the variable value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(Week)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Week FROM #yt) AS Weeks

--execute (@ColumnName)
print @ColumnName
```

the output is `[1],[2],[3]`

Can anyone explain how this works

Comment: select @ColumnName

Comment: How this works? [Badly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): "Don't use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. Because, all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) aren't necessarily run exactly once for each output row."

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is quite simple:

When run in a serial plan (non-parallelized), each row coming out of the `SELECT` will take the existing value of `@ColumnName` and concatenate it.

If it is run in a parallel plan, it can return incorrect results due to race conditions between different threads. **Therefore, you must use `OPTION(MAXDOP 1)` in such a query.**

In any case, even serial plans are [not guaranteed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) by SQL Server to return correct results, just that people have always observed them to do so, and that may change.

**So you are much better off using a proper aggregation function, such as `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML PATH`**